# Enable dragging for only one uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I've got a `UITableViewController` which has a custom `UITableViewCell`.
This cell has got a `UIScrollView`, and on dragging it shows hidden buttons.

Everything works perfectly, it also disables `UITableView` scroll while dragging, unfortunately I can't disable multi-dragging (if I use 2 or more fingers on more cells it drags all these cells).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here- what is "multi-dragging?" Also, is your question about Objective-C or Swift, as you have both of them tagged.

Comment: Multi dragging means that now I can swipe multiple cells in the same time. What I'm looking for is to permit only to drag one cell at time. I'm developing in swift, but I included also objective c because I've also developed in objective c, so it's easy for me to translate from objective c to swift!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by assigning a tag to every scroll view and adding 2 functions which:

1 function: disable scrolling of every scroll with an id different from the one which is scrolling.

Code:

```
  func disableScrolling(tag:Int){
        for var i = 0; i < count cells; ++i{
            If(i != tag){
               var scroll:UIScrollView? = self.view.viewWithTag(i) as? UIScrollView
               scroll!.scrollEnabled =false
            }
       }
    }
```

In the other function it enables scrolling of every UIScrollView.

Then I call these functions in UIScrollView delegate methods